# sql compare column values and return larger row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very simple table here. All I want to do is return the row or rows where the student is in the higher grade. I am a beginner in SQL and am unsure of how to solve this.

Table

```
Name   Grade   Class
Jim        7   Math
Jim        8   English
Emily      6   Science
Jason     11   Biology
Jason     11   Art
Jason     10   English
```

Expected Output

```
Name   Grade   Class
Jim        8   English
Emily      6   Science
Jason     11   Biology
Jason     11   Art
```

Comment: Seems like higher grade is defined a *Grade >=  8*, so simply add that as a WHERE-condition:  `WHERE Grade >= 8`

Comment: Looks like home work. If it is, you should read your school papers to learn this ;)

Comment: If the higher grade why jason with grade 10 not show?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following type query:

```
SELECT T1.Name,Grade,Class FROM Table T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT Name,MAX(Grade) MaxGrade FROM Table GROUP BY Name) T2 ON T1.Name=T2.Name AND T1.Grade=T2.MaxGrade
```

Answer (score 1):

A canonical way to do this uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.grade = (select max(t2.grade) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```

SQL Server has another interesting method:

```
select top (1) t.*
from t
order by dense_rank() over (partition by name order by grade desc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.Name
    , t.Grade
    , t.Class
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , Part = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Grade DESC)
    FROM @t
) t
WHERE t.Part = 1
```